# Extract value from Spark Streaming DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have a kafka source from where I'm receiving the HDFS path information. I want to access the paths from the Structured streaming dataframe.

Basically I want to execute a function for every row in the dataframe.

As Streaming dataframe does not support collect operation, how do I acheive this?

So far I have tried the below approach. But this doesn't seem to work.

```
val df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").options(kafkaProps).option("startingOffsets","earliest").load()

val query = df.writeStream.foreachBatch((data: DataFrame, bid: Long) => {
      val paths = data.select("value").collect()
      paths.foreach(x=>spark.read.parquet(x).show()).start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Any help is appretiated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of collecting the content of each dataframe, you can apply a foreach or a foreachPartition on it in order to do whatever you like.

```
df.writeStream.foreachBatch((data: DataFrame, bid: Long) => data.foreachPartition( # whatever you like, like reading a file))
```

In your specific case I'm wondering why you need to do a foreachBatch in the first place, a foreach could do the job no ?

```
df.writeStream.foreach(# whatever you like, like reading a file)
```